# Adding EventListeners to newly created DOM elements

Tags: javascript, dom, typescript

Hi im currently making a mini project just for practice but i came across this problem. The loop work for the hard coded code, but not the dynamiclly type one

```
<button class='agree'>Add Like</button>
```

then i have a function to basiclly adding number of likes bellow it.

```
for(var i = 0; i < agreeBtn.length; i++) {
  agreeBtn[i].addEventListener('click', plusAgree)
}

function plusAgree (e) {
      let newNum =  Number(this.children[1].innerText) + 1;
      this.children[1].innerText = newNum;
}
```

this code works fine for the hard coded button elements. But when i apply it to a new element which i have just created with createElement and innerHTML (dynamicly typed), the event listeners just doesn't work anymore.

```
    let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.className = 'boxshadow post-div grid-x';
    newDiv.innerHTML = `
    <div class="cell small-10">
          <h3 id='post-title'>${postContent.title}</h3>
          <p id='post-description'>${postContent.description}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="cell small-2 icon-div" id="icon-div">
          <button class='agree' id=${agreeId()}>
            <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up fa-3x"></i>
            <h5 class='agree-num'></h5>
          </button>
```

how can i change the this for the dynamiclly typed one to refer to the button, instead of the global object? thanks

[![ Here is the result for hardcoded 
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0VS1.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0VS1.png)

[![This is what i got from the newly created element
][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3GbJ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3GbJ.png)

Comment: How exactly do you apply it to a newly created element?

Comment: the same way as in above. Using the for loop. It didn't notified me in the console, so i tried console.log (this) and it refers to the global object.

Comment: Please add the code where you render the buttons.

Comment: Whereas when i clicked the hardcoded button it refers to the button itself

Comment: @AngelChristy The code in for loop works (as you correctly noticed) in one case, but doesn't work in another. Please add to the question the actual difference between those cases; just a generic description of that difference is not enough.

Comment: Pass the element as a function argument to refer to it. `this` refers to the global object because the function is in the global scope.

Comment: Ok i have changed it.

Comment: @Daan how do i refer the argument to that specific buttton instead of the other button ?

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the global object because the function gets invoked in the global scope.

It's best to use the [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method here.

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   `this` keyword set to the provided value.

Here is an example:

```js
const agreeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("agree");

for (var i = 0; i < agreeBtn.length; i++) {
  const el = agreeBtn[i];
  el.addEventListener('click', plusAgree.bind(el));
}

function plusAgree(e) {
  console.log(this);
}
```

```html
<button id="agree1" class="agree">Agree Button</button>
<button id="agree2" class="agree">Agree Button</button>
```